# WP7 MediaElement Unable to Reposition the stream

Tags: windows-phone-7, video-streaming

I am using `MediaElement` for video playback in my app. I have added controls for play, pause, rewind and forward. In the forward button's event handler, I am trying to forward the video clip for 5 seconds. the code I have used to do that is given below.

```
if(myMediaElement.CanSeek)
{
    myMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    myMediaElement.Play();
}
```

But the video clip does not forward, instead it stops the video playback. Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start playing the stream before you can set the position.

Move the call to `CanSeek` and the setting of the position until after the `MediaOpened` event has been raised.

See the remarks in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.position(v=VS.95).aspx for confirmation.

Comment: As you suggested, in the MediaOpened event, I called CanSeek(), it returned true, then in the next line am setting the Position as "myMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);". but the same thing happens, it stops the video playback and MediaFailed event is fired. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Using valueconverter sample here, with Slider adjustments, to get the positions
http://diggthedrazen.com/2011/07/08/using-an-ivalueconverter-to-create-a-player-with-a-seek-bar-on-windows-phone/